# How to recognize a swipe gesture in a specific area?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, gesture

I'm working on an Air Android app and I would like to show and hide a menu based on a users gesture.
How to set the gesture recognition to a specific area instead to the whole stage? (e.g. the area from y 0 to 100 px)

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE , onSwipe); 

function onSwipe (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
if (e.offsetY == 1) { 
 //User swiped towards bottom
showMenu()
 }
 else if (e.offsetY == -1) { 
 //User swiped towards top
hideMenu()
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a component to the stage (empty sprite container lets call it mySprite) with the proper dimensions and location and then you have 2 options:

**option 1**

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3swipegesture/

**option 2**

add a check to see if swipe was done on mySprite

```
function onSwipe (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{\
**if (e.target=!mySprite){return}**
if (e.offsetY == 1) { 
 //User swiped towards bottom
showMenu()
 }
 else if (e.offsetY == -1) { 
 //User swiped towards top
hideMenu()
 } 
}
```

**Option 3**

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

var mySprite = new Sprite();
mySprite.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE , onSwipe);
mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0x336699);
mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 80);
var myTextField = new TextField();
myTextField.y = 200;
addChild(mySprite);
addChild(myTextField);

function onSwipe(evt:TransformGestureEvent):void {

    if (evt.offsetX == 1 ) {
    myTextField.text = "right";
    }
    if (evt.offsetY == -1) {
    myTextField.text = "up";
    }
    myTextField.text = evt.phase;

}
```

Comment: I can't use a sprite because it would overlay a text field. Is there an option to use xy coordinates instead?